# Is there something similar to \graphicspath{ {myPath} } for minted?

Tags: minted

Basically what the title says. I would like to know if there is a way to specify a particular folder as a base folder for when you import source code files in minted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's currently no provision for this. However, it's not difficult to add a suitable framework.

I used a couple of directories created for answering other questions just by way of example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pathinputminted}[3][]{%
  \expandafter\@tfor\expandafter\next\expandafter:\expandafter=\pathminted@path\do{%
    \IfFileExists{\next #3}{\inputminted[#1]{#2}{\next #3}}{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\mintedpath}[1]{%
  \def\pathminted@path{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\mintedpath{{./zeno/}{wenneker/}}

\begin{document}

\pathinputminted{latex}{a.tex}

\pathinputminted{latex}{b.tex}

\pathinputminted{tex}{chsum.tex}

\end{document}
```

This is quite simplistic, because all files named `a.tex` in directories specified in `\mintedpath` will be input.

It would be possible to break the loop at the first hit, but it's easier with `expl3`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_mintedpath_paths_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\mintedpath}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_mintedpath_paths_tl { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\pathinputminted}{O{}mm}
 {
  \tl_map_inline:Nn \l_mintedpath_paths_tl
   {
    \file_if_exist:nT { ##1 #3 }
     {
      \inputminted[#1]{#2}{##1 #3}
      \tl_map_break:
     }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\mintedpath{{./zeno/}{./wenneker/}}

\begin{document}

\pathinputminted{latex}{a.tex}

\pathinputminted{latex}{b.tex}

\pathinputminted{tex}{chsum.tex}

\end{document}
```